# "undefined local variable or method `n' for main:Object" when trying to run "rake db:populate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rake

I'm going through Michael Hartl's tutorial and I can't get the error:

```
undefined local variable or method `n' for main:Object
```

when I run `bundle exec rake db:populate`

**sample_data.rake file**

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    name  = Faker::Name.name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
    password  = "password"
    User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have n inside interpolated string next to email and it is not defined anywhere. Remove or define it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize the `n` variable to `0` at the beginning of your script, just before `name`.

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    n = 0
    name  = Faker::Name.name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
    password  = "password"
    User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
  end
end
```

This piece of code was probably used in a loop. Here you actually don't need the `n`.